# One class requires another and that other class requires the first one. How do I do that?

Tags: c++

Here we have two classes, let's call it `Tree` and `Fruit`. A `Tree` can only have one or no `Fruit`s at any given time. A `Fruit` can only be on one `Tree`. From the `Tree` object, you can get its `Fruit` by the function `getTreeFruit( )`. From the `Fruit` object, you can get its "owner" by the function `getFruitOwner( )` which returns a `Tree` object.

Now in the `Tree` header, we have this:

```
#include "Fruit.h"
class Tree {
   private:
      Fruit m_Fruit; // The fruit in the tree.

   public:
      Tree ( Fruit tree_fruit );
      Fruit getTreeFruit( ); // Returns m_Fruit.
}
```

And on the `Fruit` header:

```
#include "Tree.h"
class Fruit {
   private:
      Tree m_Owner; // The Tree object that "owns" the fruit.

   public:
      Fruit ( Tree fruit_owner );
      Tree getFruitOwner( ); // Returns m_Owner.
}
```

I realized that `Tree` and `Fruit` include each other's header files and this causes an error. How do I go about fixing the error?

Thanks a lot in advanced. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realized that Tree and Fruit include each other's header files and this causes an error.

This is not the only problem. Basically you want two objects to contain each other recursively, which is not possible.

What you probably want is to make fruit have a pointer to the tree it belongs to, and forward-declare `Tree` in `Fruit.h` like so:

Tree.h:

```
#include "Fruit.h"
class Tree 
{
    private:
        Fruit m_Fruit; // The fruit in the tree.

    public:
        Tree (Fruit tree_fruit);
        Fruit getTreeFruit(); // Returns m_Fruit.
}
```

Fruit.h

```
class Tree;

class Fruit 
{
    private:
        Tree* m_Owner; // The Tree object that "owns" the fruit.

    public:
        Fruit(Tree* fruit_owner);
        Tree* getFruitOwner(); // Returns m_Owner.
}
```

Comment: I did this. It worked. Now, I have another method called `drawFruit( )` which takes the `Fruit` owner's `x` position and uses that value to position the fruit after some math. However, I get the error saying `Member access to incomplete type 'Tree'`. What does that mean? Do I have to include `Tree.h` in my `Fruit.cpp`? The `Tree`'s `x` value is public, by the way.

Comment: I am getting an error saying `Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "Fruit::Fruit()", referenced from:
      Tree::Tree(std::string const&) in Tree.o
      Tree::Tree(int, int, std::string const&) in Tree.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386`

Comment: @LanceGray ensure you are linking everything together. Might be worth creating another question though.

Answer (score 3):

You should be storing *references* to the Tree in the Fruit objects, not the tree itself.

References are a better choice than pointers here, because they express the condition that fruit can't magically hop from one tree to another. A reference can only be set when an object is constructed, so you have to use an initializer list in the constructor.

Then, you can use a forward declaration of Tree.

```
  class Tree;

  class Fruit {
   private:
      Tree &owner; // The Tree object that "owns" the fruit.

   public:
      Fruit (Tree &fruit_owner ) : owner(fruit_owner)
      { ... };

      Tree &getFruitOwner( ); // Returns owner.
```

Answer (score 1):

use forward declaration of the class and make the tree as pointer

```
class Tree;
class Fruit {
   private:
      Tree *m_pOwner; // The Tree object that "owns" the fruit.

   public:
      Fruit ( Tree *fruit_owner );
      Tree* getFruitOwner( ); // Returns m_Owner.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `forward declaration`:

```
class Tree;

class Fruit {
   private:
      Tree *m_Owner; // The Tree object that "owns" the fruit.

   public:
      Fruit ( Tree *fruit_owner );
      Tree *getFruitOwner( ); // Returns m_Owner.
}
```